# How can I add a comma to JSON data in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

```json
{
    "positif": 1797499,
    "dirawat": 98405,
    "sembuh": 1649187,
    "meninggal": 49907,
    "lastUpdate": "2021-05-27T09:42:08.000Z"
}
```

How can I add a comma to the JSON data? For example,  convert "1797499" to "1,797,499"

Answer (score 0):

Using the below function, you can change from an `int` value to a `String` added comma.

```
newData = numberWithComma(json['positif'])
...

String numberWithComma(param) {
  if (param == null) {
    return '0';
  }
  return NumberFormat('###,###,###,###').format(param).replaceAll(' ', '');
}
```